# TypeScript multiple generics, partial infer

Tags: typescript

I have a function where 1 generic gets passed in, but the other should be inferred from an argument passed to the function. I can't work out how to make them behave differently, the TS compiler just wants me to pass in both types. Any advice on how to do this would be appreciated!

Hard to explain so probably better to use an example:
[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtxXQGx9AHgDEQAlCAZwAdMKIAaAFQD5kBvZAek%20TjGTAALFAFt0IiOGQly1WijggAJska8ooxUr7ooATwHpkAIxRU4FOitAA6G8gCSyTDgMB3RfzBHzl5KGkyShoQOl5lVWQKQXQAVxwVU38QGGgNFRhsEQFhZAByRT0hUABzPPUSgChkcKLBUoAuVQBuauQEODxjRABrIliQBDBgTCaACg4YdCMAXwbJ6YaKMChS5BmASmQAXlYZYPlKmcrK0EhYRBRUTpxuhB7ZELC2NrF0JuXVkCrjyoRafigZaKJAARiaGCwuHwUAI1y6vUe8lY23YXB4SkowHSyCmUBEfGQYxA6H41AgCGAMD0axKkmgwAQAj0VBQePyhWK3zyGzanPq3yaACJ%20aUhfQ2h0Efd%20oNhqMiQtZltduw2jUNGBYlAQGqavrkG9hd0oEL1etWjVjjNWid-qFAQ6QRAAEwQzAraGEeG3REHUIMQootHcZBuXQ9ODYAYqPjZMbkynU2n01ZMsAstm6DkgOqlHl83NckrC0XfcWSm53PoDIYjEDjJXrFWsF4GzXa3Vtg2GxbIIUms0Gm1ta22oA)

Comment: Open issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571

Comment: This is not currently possible directly, although there are workarounds, such as writing a curried helper function as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wXqGVN).  See the linked question and answers for more information.